# How to detect class and field names for data in android heap?

Tags: java, android, heap-memory, dalvik

I have memory address in android java heap. How I can determine class and field linked with this memory address?

For example I have next class:

```
class Bear {
    int speed;
    int weight;
    int size;

    void run() {
    }

    bool isSleep() {
    }
}
```

And object `b` with fields: 10, 20 and 30 for `speed`, `weight` and `size`.

I have memory address of field `width` but I don't know what is this. How I can get data about this memory address like `Bear.weight`?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @hoomi Develop memory hacker.

Comment: Have a look at the source code of MAT. That may help you how to find the class type from the memory address. https://eclipse.org/mat/

Answer (score 0):

From [dalvik/vm/oo/Object.h](http://osxr.org/android/source/dalvik/vm/oo/Object.h) I found the following path:

1. From the desired address of the memory go back considering each dword as pointer.
2. If the pointer is correct and points to the structure of the descriptor class, we find the beginning of the `DataObject`. Top of the class structure of the descriptor indicates the general state the structure of the descriptor class that points to itself, because it is also a class descriptor.
3. At offset 24 bytes to describe the structure of a class is a pointer to a null terminated strings with the name of the class described by this structure. For the overall structure is to be `"Ljava/lang/Class;"`. For our example - `"Lcom/android/example/spinner/Bear;"`.
4. At offset 136 bytes to be int with the number of class fields.
5. At offset 144 - a pointer to the array of fields.
6. At offset 156 - the number of static fields.
7. At offset 160 - an array of static fields.
8. The structure corresponding to the field consists of three pointers and two dword. The first pointer is a pointer to a class, second - zero terminated string with the name, third - also zero terminated string, but with the type of field. Then dword with access flags and dword with offset in DataObject.

Thus, if we find the right class for DataObject, we will be able to understand the basis of the offset fields what is field use this memory address.

Comment: You may want to look at the way the hprof heap dump is created (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/hprof/Hprof.cpp#225). If you don't to run the heap while the VM is running, you can just process the hprof output.

Comment: @fadden 1. A heap not of my process, so I can not tell where it begins. 2. There is much more complicated than `dalvik/vm/oo/Object.h`. 3. Format `hprof` different from what is in the memory. 4. I need real-time data. 5. I have limited resources. It makes no sense to do a full dump of the heap if I need two classes.

Comment: The point was more to look at the way the hprof heap dump code walked through the heap -- from looking at the code you can see how it processes each object.